# WPF RelyCommand binds but doesn't execute?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, mvvm-light

I have a command that binds to the view model, is enabled, but doesn't always execute.  How can I go about debugging this?  I used WPF Inspector and it re confirms that the binding is correct.

More Detail:
I have a tab control that only executes the command for tabs to close when the tab is not selected.  When the tab is selected the command will not hit.

The code is fairly standard and I can't seem to see or debug the probems.

The templated close button on TabItem

```
                <Style x:Key="ClosableStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadTabItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                                <telerik:RadButton Grid.Column="1" Margin="3 1 -4 0" Width="16" Height="16" Opacity="0.7" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="x" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT" FontSize="12" Margin="0,-3,0,0" />
                                </telerik:RadButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

The command:

```
RelayCommand _closePanelCommand;
/// <summary>
/// Returns the command that, when invoked, attempts
/// to remove this workspace from the user interface.
/// </summary>
public virtual ICommand CloseCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_closePanelCommand == null)
        {
            _closePanelCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    this.OnRequestClose();
                }
            );
        }

        return _closePanelCommand;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also recommend using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) which is a UI debugging utility that is essential for this kind of debugging. Otherwise you're flying blind.

The thing with a `Button` is that if the Command binding fails(which happens silently) the `Button` stays Enabled so you don't know if the button is Enabled because the `ICommand` says so or because the binding failed.

You can also look at your output window which should tell you if the binding failed, but snoop is quite a bit easier than reading through a bunch of text in your output window :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your problem is you are trying to use ICommand as an INotifiableProperty which won't work like this. You need to provide the handler for your command in your ViewModel's constructor something like this -

```
this.CloseCommand= new RelayCommand(param => this.OnRequestClose(param));
```

And just write your property like this -

```
public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: Here 'param' is any commandparameter you want to send along with your command from xaml. In case you dont want any parameters you can declare just like you did in your property. But i'll refer to use this syntax.

Comment: I think the propblem has been misunderstood.  OnRequestClose works when it gets to that line.   The OnRequestClsor is taken from Josh Smiths MVVM example and is pretty boiler plate.

Comment: You wrote that sometimes your command don't execute, can you be more specific about cases when it don't and can you provide code when you have handled the situation that your command wont fire if your tabitem is selected. May be that can be of any help

Answer (score 0):

you should check the actual datacontext of your button (take Snoop). i think that the datacontext is not right in case your command get not fired.